# Trigger to update lastModified column automatically in MSSQL server using scope_identity()

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that automatically updates a column for an entry in my table when that specific entry is updated.

The table name is "accounts". The column name is "modified" (it is a dateTime that states when this entry was last updated).

I am using SCOPE_IDENTITY() to point to the entry which I wish to update.

The trigger is created successfully, but when I update an entry, the column "modified" does not change. perhaps I'm using SCOPE_IDENTITY() incorrectly? Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateModified
ON dbo.accounts
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.accounts
    SET modified = GETDATE()
    WHERE sysID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is only *ever* set to a meaningful value by `INSERT` statements, so in an `after update` trigger, it wouldn't be meaningful - and doubly so because of the "scope" part of the name. The trigger's scope is different from the scope of the statement that *issued* the DML your trigger fires in response to.

Comment: thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I'm new to SQL...any suggestions on how I might accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`inserted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) table to tell you which row(**s**) have just been updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateModified
ON dbo.accounts
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(modified) RETURN; --Don't react recursively
    UPDATE dbo.accounts
    SET modified = GETDATE()
    WHERE sysID in (select sysID from inserted)
```

Comment: +1 I was just typing this out.  Would it be more efficient to join to the `inserted` table based on `sysID`?

Comment: @JefferyKhan - it's simple enough that either way should produce the same actual execution plan.